Django ratelimit ignores the set rate and blocks all requests
I am encountering a curious case of having all my POST requests blocked when I use ratelimit on my view.
I am using a docker that runs the db and memcached services with the following configuration:
    memcached:
      image: memcached
      ports:
        - "11211:11211"
      entrypoint:
        - memcached
        - -m 64

I am using pymemcache:
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyMemcacheCache",
        "LOCATION": "memcached:11211",  
        "OPTIONS": {
            "allow_unicode_keys": True,
            "default_noreply": False,
            "serde": pymemcache.serde.pickle_serde,
        },
    }
}

and I want to ratelimit the login POST request:
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page
from django.core.cache import cache

def rate_limit_exceeded(request, *args, **kwargs):
    ip_address = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    logger.debug(f"Rate limit exceeded function called for IP: {ip_address}, Method: {request.method}")
    return JsonResponse({"error": "Rate limit exceeded. Please try again later."}, status=429)

@method_decorator(ratelimit(key='ip', rate='10/m', method='POST', block=False), name="post")
class Default_LoginView(DefaultLoginView):   
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Post method called")
        ip_address = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
        for attr in dir(request):
            try:
                print(f"{attr}: {getattr(request, attr)}")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Could not retrieve {attr}: {e}")
        print("*************")      
        should_ratelimit = getattr(request, "limited", False)

        print(f"IP Address: {ip_address}")
        print(f"Rate limited: {should_ratelimit}")

        # Increment the request count for this IP address
        cache_key = f"ip_request_count_{ip_address}"
        request_count = cache.get(cache_key, 0) + 1
        cache.set(cache_key, request_count, timeout=3600)  # Set timeout to 1 hour
        print(f"IP Address: {ip_address}, Request Count: {request_count}")

        if should_ratelimit:
            print("Rate limit exceeded")
            return rate_limit_exceeded(request)  
        print("Rate limit not exceeded")      
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print("Form is valid")
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        next_url = self.request.GET.get("next")
        if next_url:
            return redirect(next_url)
        else:
            return redirect(reverse("login_success"))

When I make a POST request in my login view (try to login), the reesponse always has the parameter 'limited = True' and thus triggers the rate_limit_exceeded function.
Here are the terminal printouts:
[05/Sep/2024 08:58:29] "GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2396
Post method called
IP Address: 127.0.0.1
Rate limited: True
IP Address: 127.0.0.1, Request Count: 1
Rate limit exceeded
Too Many Requests: /login/
[05/Sep/2024 08:58:35] "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 429 57


I am quite certain of something being configured incorrectly, but I am not sure I can identify whether its in the memcached service or elsewhere.
Any ideas?
